# Single user access to a visualforce page at a time in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I need to implement functionality in which for some visualforce page "xyz" access is available to one user at a time for some specific time, lets say for 5 minutes. And want to display a notification message if some other user tries to access that page in these 5 mins.

Moreover i dont want to create any custom object for this functionality, can i do it with session?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use custom settings. 
Create new one with information about user and time. And in controller you can easy check information stored in custom settings and add this notification

Comment: Ok. But would i need to reset those after that time slot expires? And through what means i should reset if i need to?